# New to S3, not sure what to put in my Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Basically I'm storing my images in buckets on S3. But I'm having trouble what to put in my Bucket Policy. Pretty much I want to know what I have below for one of my buckets is

A) Correct
B) Safe

Goal: To read/display the images from my [app server]

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::submissionthumbs/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "[APPIP]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to read, write, and delete assets from the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If under stand this right you have 2 usecases:

1. Showing the images to your users from s3
2. Uploading, deleting and changing images from your app.

1: For that you will need to make your bucket or parts of it public readable.
For example this as a bucket policy will make the content of the bucket public readable

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "*" },
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::submissionthumbs/*" ]
   }]
}
```

However you may want to take a look at amazon CloudFront which is the amazon CDN to deliver you images. In CloudFront you can add your s3 bucket as a origin.

2: For updating uploading etc, you should create a new "user" from "IAM" and give him read and write access to the bucket. Try to keep the permissions as restricted as possible.
For example

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Sid": "AllowReadWriteApp",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::submissionthumbs/*" ]
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then use your favorite aws sdk for your programming language for the CRUD operations.

Hope that helps